# How to determine in which esriTransformDirection we need to use in ArcObject IGeometry5 ProjectEx

Tags: esri, arcmap, arcobjects, esri-arc-engine

I am working on a project in which i need to calculate the points form on CRS to another, but as we the source and target CRS are only determine on runtime.

```
ISpatialReference source = GCS_North_American_1983

ISpatialReference target = UTM Zone 13 North (108 W - 102 W Longitude)

IEnvelope extent = rasterLayer.VisibleExtent;

Console.WriteLine(extent.XMax);   == -97.815540361118

Console.WriteLine(extent.XMin);   == -102.045540576002

Console.WriteLine(extent.YMax);   == 39.933228902485

Console.WriteLine(extent.YMin);   == 37.113228759229

IGeoTransformation geoTransformation = "NAD_1927_To_NAD_1983_NADCON"

geoTransformationOperationSet.Set(esriTransformDirection.esriTransformForward, geoTransformation);
            geoTransformationOperationSet.Set(esriTransformDirection.esriTransformReverse, geoTransformation);
```

//So we need to go in reverse order. as source is in NAD83 and Target is in NAD27. and ***returns correct results matched with ArcMap but going forward results wrong output.***

```
geometry.ProjectEx(target, esriTransformDirection.esriTransformReverse, geoTransformation, false, 0.0, 0.0);


Console.WriteLine(extent.XMax);  ==  1138797.89197912

Console.WriteLine(extent.XMin);  ==  752503.366222885

Console.WriteLine(extent.YMax);  ==  4444925.18943959

Console.WriteLine(extent.YMin);  ==  4111314.85519851
```

if we do the forward transformation return **incorrect result**.

```
1138738.17611084

752424.161510695

4444923.04572637

4111317.16066915
```

So how can I determine which direction we need to use? Like forward/reverse. Is there any way we can find out using arcobject API return use fwd or reverse. I looked into the `IGeoTransformation` but no success, there are many different predefined GeoTransformation which can use in both fwd or reverse if supported.

Thanks.